Go to another sheet using apps script
I'm trying to create a project that has too many sheets, so to easily navigate through those sheets, I decided to create a drop down list with all of the sheet names and to create a button to go to the selected sheet.

Below is my script:
function openTab() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form=ss.getSheetByName("REGISTRY");
  var landing=form.getRange("I11").getValue();
  var datasheet=ss.getSheetByName(landing);
  datasheet.activate();
}

When I try to run this script, it returns this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'activate')
"REGISTRY" is the name of the sheet which has the dropdown, and "I11" is the exact cell where the dropdown is located.

I think that the reason for your error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'activate') is due to that datasheet is null. So, in your situation, how about confirming the value landing and checking whether the sheet name of the value landing is included in the active Google Spreadsheet?

Thanks for replying! I checked my form and I noticed that the cell where the dropdown is located is merged from I10:I11. I changed it to "I10" and the code works now.

Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Also, I believe that Wicket's answer will be useful for a lot of users.

The error likely occurred because ss.getSheetByName(landing) returned null. This happens when no sheet matches the parameter's value.
First, you should ensure that the script reads the correct cell.
If the correct cell is read, the easiest fix is to ensure that the dropdown values in cell I11 include only the names of existing sheets. A more practical fix might consist of a validation and a way to give feedback to the end-user / spreadsheet owner.
One way to do this is by using an if statement and SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(message).

Google Sheets already include built-in features to navigate across sheets.
One of these features is the All Sheets button next to the Add sheet button. Clicking this button shows a list; when there are too many, it includes a vertical scroll bar as shown in the following snapshot:

